# How to deploy PCFDev on AWS

Tags: cloud, cloud-foundry, pcfdev

There is the page "[PCF Dev on AWS](https://docs.pivotal.io/pcf-dev/aws.html)" on Pivotal Cloud Foundry documentations.
But there are not many explanations how to do it, how to deploy PCFDev on AWS. 
So, is there somewhere more detailed explanation, or can anyone give the guide how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find more information about how to install PCF with Bosh Lite on AWS [here](https://cloud.gov/docs/ops/creating-a-development-environment-with-bosh-lite/).